# Scala parallel collections and mutable state

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I have a function, that performs one step of computation by updating a map (underlying is a mutable HashMap). I want to do several of these computations in parallel (each "chain" working on its own mutable HashMap).

I did this by putting the HashMaps into a parallel collection and applying the function to each HashMap, by using map.

Now I have experienced missing entries inside the maps. When debugging, the map contains the entry once the exception breakpoint stops the program (and restarting the computation a bit earlier by discarding some layers of stack frames works then).

This behavior is gone when I am using sequential collections. So is it possible, that there is some misbehaviour (or bug), that is caused by the same HashMap gets worked on in different Threads?

I didn't post a code example, since I don't think the behaviour is reproducible. To the best of my knowledge, the only mutable data is contained inside those HashMaps, that hold the state of the computation.

On request a the sample of my code where the parallel map is created (`reset`) and modified (`step`).

```
class ParallelInferer[V <: DiscreteVariable, TInf <: InferenceAlgorithm[V]](val numChains: Int,
                                              val inferer: InferenceAlgorithm[V],
                                              val random: Random) {
  //tuples of inferer state and the according random number generator
  protected var states: ParSeq[(inferer.Repr,Random)] = _
  protected var steps = 0

  reset()

  def reset() {
    steps = 0

    val seed = random.nextInt()

    //todo why does parallelizing fail here (key not found on a map)
    states = (1 to numChains).par
      .map(n => new Random(seed + n))    //create the rngs
      .map(rng => (inferer.createInitialState(rng),rng))
  }

  def step() {
    //advance every chain by one
    states = states.map{case (repr, rng) => (inferer.computeStep(repr, rng),rng)}
    steps = steps + 1
  }
}
```

### Explanation of the code

The `ParallelInferer` class is intended (also) for immutable inference. So, the mutability is not directly visible inside the posted code, but I think it's the important part that is shown.

Each inference algorithm has a notion of state, this state is of type `InferenceAlgorithm#Repr` - as apparent in the usage of `inferer.Repr` as part of the `states` variable. The inferers work by mapping a `Repr` (and a Random object) to a new `Repr` with their `computeStep` function. This can be seen in `def step()`. Now some inferers use a mutable `HashMap` as part of their state. Their `computeStep` method returns the same map that it got as argument, after mutating it.

## Question

1. Can I somehow fix this behaviour?
2. Am I misusing parallel collections and should parallelize my task differenty?

### Edit

I've just run the parallelized version again, and I think it also causes the algorithm to not terminate, although it does when running sequentially. Well, not *that* surprising, isn't it?

Can someone speculate on why this is happening?

Comment: Any meaningful (and short code) that you can provide that shows the issues and is still relevant to your use case?

Comment: I don't see any hash maps. Is it in `inferer`?

Comment: Uh, I didn't think much when putting the code in. See the edit.

Comment: I think the code you showed is fine as long as you can make `createInitialState` and `computeStep` thread safe. See if you can make inferers not share any state, as what you showed seems to parallelize nicely.

Comment: I also think that the code should be ok, unless the hash maps inside the repr objects are shared...

Comment: @axel22 They're not shared. `createInitialState` creates fresh state objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  Mutable HashMaps are by default not thread-safe, and using them in this manner can result in undefined behaviour.  Missing entries is actually a fairly benign manifestation.  Depending on the underlying implementation, it also possible to corrupt the HashMap data structure to the point where your program goes into an infinite loop.

There are a lot of ways to fix this, which will have different coding complexities and performance tradeoffs.  The easiest is to just use a synchronized hash map rather than an unsynchronized one.

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

val map = new HashMap[Key, Value] with SynchronizedMap[Key, Value]
```

I wouldn't say the root problem is that you are using parallel collections incorrectly, but rather that *any* parallel program using mutable data structures is going to have issues like this.  A much more Scala-ish way to do this would be to use immutable maps, and have your parallel processing steps return new immutable maps.  This sounds computationally expensive, but isn't necessarily, due to the underlying implementation of immutable hash maps.

Comment: As a supplemental to your last sentence: [Extreme Cleverness: Functional Data Structures in Scala](http://vimeo.com/20262239)

Comment: Are you sure that using a synchronized map is enough? Doesn't it only assert, that its state stays consistent. It doesn't get the accesses in the correct order.

Comment: @ziggystar: Very good point - the `SynchronizedMap` map mixin ensures that all the accesses to the map are synchronized so that you do not get spurious errors. Order is still not defined - in general, this is one thing that parallel collections do not ensure and elements will be processed out of order.

Comment: The thing that I am expecting is, that after one batch of computation has been done on the collection, then the result is not completely written back to the maps before the next step starts. Then this map gets processed by a different thread and the error happens. Will such an issue be resolved by using a Synchronized collection? It has to do with using `volatile` (at least in C/C++).

Comment: Yes, using a Synchronized collection will prevent that.  Synchronization provides the necessary memory model gaurantees (like using volatile) so that writes in one thread will be available to reads in another thread.